# switch column values in dataframe in R based in combination of two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question about changing character values in a data.frame according to combinations based in two columns. I will try to give an example of how de data.frame looks

```
data <- data.frame(A1 = c("A", "T", "C"), A2 = c("C", "G", "T"), 
                   Ind1 = c("AA", "TG", "TT"), Ind2 = c("CA", "GT", "CT"),
                   Ind3 = c("AC", "GG", "TC"))

> data
  A1 A2 Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
1  A  C   AA   CA   AC
2  T  G   TG   GT   GG
3  C  T   TT   CT   TC
```

I want to change the values in columns from Ind1 to Ind3 that don't match the possible combinations from columns `A1` and `A2`, for example in the first row, `A1` is an `A` and `A2` is a `C` so the possible combinations would be `AA`, `AC`, `CC` (combination based on `A1`, and `A2` in that order). Therefore the Ind2 should be `AC` instead of `CA`.

The desired output would be this one:

```
> data
  A1 A2 Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
1  A  C   AA   AC   AC
2  T  G   TG   TG   GG
3  C  T   TT   CT   CT
```

I have tried with `switch` but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly and assuming you only have two letters to deal with there is only one case which will need editing;  that is when the letters are in reverse order i.e. 'A2A1'. All other cases will be correct. So you could manage this with a simple `ifelse` mutate.

```r
data <- data.frame(A1 = c("A", "T", "C"), A2 = c("C", "G", "T"), 
                   Ind1 = c("AA", "TG", "TT"), Ind2 = c("CA", "GT", "CT"),
                   Ind3 = c("AC", "GG", "TC"))

library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Ind"), ~ ifelse(.x == paste0(A2, A1), paste0(A1, A2), .x)))
#>   A1 A2 Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
#> 1  A  C   AA   AC   AC
#> 2  T  G   TG   TG   GG
#> 3  C  T   TT   CT   CT
```

In response to OP comments, using "real" data:

```r
df2 <- structure(list(chr = "chr11", pos = "74565122", snp_id = "chr11_74565122_C_T_b38",     Allele1 = "C", Allele2 = "T", GTEX_111CU = "TT", GTEX_111YS = "CT",     GTEX_1122O = "TC", GTEX_117XS = "TC", GTEX_117YX = "TC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

df2
#>     chr      pos                 snp_id Allele1 Allele2 GTEX_111CU GTEX_111YS
#> 1 chr11 74565122 chr11_74565122_C_T_b38       C       T         TT         CT
#>   GTEX_1122O GTEX_117XS GTEX_117YX
#> 1         TC         TC         TC

mutate(df2, across(starts_with("GTEX"), ~ ifelse(.x %in% paste0(Allele2, Allele1), paste0(Allele1, Allele2), .x)))
#>     chr      pos                 snp_id Allele1 Allele2 GTEX_111CU GTEX_111YS
#> 1 chr11 74565122 chr11_74565122_C_T_b38       C       T         TT         CT
#>   GTEX_1122O GTEX_117XS GTEX_117YX
#> 1         CT         CT         CT
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I have tried with some real data but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why. A real example would be this `dput(df2)
structure(list(chr = "chr11", pos = "74565122", snp_id = "chr11_74565122_C_T_b38",
    Allele1 = "C", Allele2 = "T", `GTEX-111CU` = "TT", `GTEX-111YS` = "CT",
    `GTEX-1122O` = "TC", `GTEX-117XS` = "TC", `GTEX-117YX` = "TC",
    `GTEX-11DXX` = "TC", `GTEX-11DXZ` = "CC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))`, I have tried: `df2 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("GTEX"), ~ ifelse(.x %in% paste0(Allele2, Allele1), paste0(Allele1, Allele2), .x)))`

Comment: Sorry the `dput(df2)` in the comment does not work for me. I get "Error: unexpected symbol in ..."

Comment: please try this one: `structure(list(chr = "chr11", pos = "74565122", snp_id = "chr11_74565122_C_T_b38",
    Allele1 = "C", Allele2 = "T", GTEX_111CU = "TT", GTEX_111YS = "CT",
    GTEX_1122O = "TC", GTEX_117XS = "TC", GTEX_117YX = "TC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-1L))`

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, it worked. It was a problem of some package conflicts. I restarted R session and worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

Besides Peter's very clever trick, if you wanna go for a solution a bit more hard-coded in base R, you can `split` the strings row-by-row, `sort` according to the order in A1 and A2, and `paste` back. This is agnostic to the number of letters to order:

```r
cols <- grep("Ind", colnames(data))
data[cols] <- 
  apply(data, 1, \(x){
    strsplit(x[cols], "") |> 
      sapply(\(y) factor(y, levels = x[-cols]) |> 
               sort() |> 
               paste(collapse = ""))
  })) |> 
  t()

#   A1 A2 Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
# 1  A  C   AA   AC   AC
# 2  T  G   TG   TG   GG
# 3  C  T   TT   CT   CT
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use a regex pattern to test the validity of the combo, then reverse the string if it is not valid:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data |>
  mutate(across(starts_with("Ind"), \(x) ifelse(
    str_detect(x, pattern = sprintf("^%s{0,2}%s{0,2}$", A1, A2)),
    x,
    stringi::stri_reverse(x))
  ))
#   A1 A2 Ind1 Ind2 Ind3
# 1  A  C   AA   AC   AC
# 2  T  G   TG   TG   GG
# 3  C  T   TT   CT   CT
```